# Steps in CLT proof unclear

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, central-limit-theorem

In john rice Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis we find a proof about the central limit theorem.

Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of independent random variables having variance $\sigma^2$ and the commmon distribution function $F$ and moment generating function $M$ defined in a neighborhood of zero. Let

$$S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$$

Then:

$$\lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty}P \left( \frac{S_n}{\sigma \sqrt n} \le x\right) = \Phi(x)$$

Proof:

Let $Z_n = \frac{S_n}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$

Since $S_n$ is a sum of independent random variables:

$$M_{S_n}(t) = [M(t)]^n$$

$$M_{Z_n}(t) = \left[M\left(\frac t {\sigma \sqrt n}\right)\right]^n$$

$M(s)$ has a Taylor series expansion about zero.

$$M(s) = M(0) + s M'(0) + \frac{1}{2}s^2 M''(0) + \varepsilon_s$$

where $\frac{\varepsilon_s}{s^2} \longrightarrow 0$ as $s \longrightarrow 0$.

Why is this? And why is it useful? I thought that if the denominator of a fraction converges to zero you would essentially have an expression that have a zero value in the denominator which would produce an undefined value.

Since $E(X) = 0$, $M'(0) = 0$ and $M''(0) = \sigma^2$.

As $n \longrightarrow \infty, t/(\sigma \sqrt{n}) \longrightarrow 0$

The statement $n \longrightarrow \infty, t/(\sigma 
\sqrt{n}) \longrightarrow 0$ made, but why is it useful?

$$M\left(\frac{t}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}\right) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \left(\frac{t}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}\right)^2 + \varepsilon_n$$

I assume the above follows from the fact that $s = \frac{t}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$ So you replace this into the taylor expansion, but why is $\varepsilon_{s}$ replaced with $\varepsilon_n$?

Comment: consider $2^{-n}/2^{-n}$ denominator is going to zero but always equal to 1 for any integer n

Comment: (Partial hint, hence comment) - For $\epsilon_s / s^2 \rightarrow 0$ as $s \rightarrow 0$, the reason this is the case will be more apparent if you expand the Taylor series of $M(s)$ for a few more terms and compare the latter $s$ terms in relation to $1/s^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by the latter $s$ terms?

Comment: "if the denominator of a fraction converges to zero you would essentially have an expression that have a zero value in the denominator which would produce an undefined value." $${}$$ THAT IS FALSE. All derivatives are limits as the numerator and denominator approach $0.$ If that made them undefined, then all derivatives would be undefined. If the denominator approaches $0$ while the numerator approaches something else, then the limit is undefined, but if they BOTH approach $0,$ then in many cases the limit exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if the denominator of a fraction converges to zero you would essentially have an expression that have a zero value in the denominator which would produce an undefined value."

THAT IS FALSE. All derivatives are limits as the numerator and denominator approach $0.$ If that made them undefined, then all derivatives would be undefined. If the denominator approaches $0$ while the numerator approaches something else, then the limit is undefined, but if they BOTH approach $0,$ then in many cases the limit exists.

Note that if the numerator is $s^3$ and the denomoinator is $s^2,$ then certainly the fraction approaches $0$ as $s^2\to0.$

Comment: Ok that clears up part of my confusion. Why is the fact that $\frac{\epsilon_{s}}{s^2} \longrightarrow 0$ as $s \longrightarrow 0$ even useful in the proof?

Comment: @DanielDeWet : Recall from calculus that $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1 + \frac a n \right)^n = e^a,$$ so in particular, $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{t^2}{2n} \right)^n = e^{t^2/2}.$$ But what you have is $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{t^2}{2n} + \cdots \right)^n.$$ The idea is to show that the terms appearing where those dots are do not alter the bottom line. $\qquad$

Comment: What do you mean the terms appearing where those dots are do not alter the bottom line? What is this bottom line you are talking about?

Comment: @DanielDeWet : By "the bottom line" I meant the expression to the right of the "equals" sign, i.e. $e^{t^2/2}. \qquad$

Comment: Sorry for all of the questions but I'm not sure what you mean by "altering" the expression $e^{\frac{t^{2}}{2}}$

Comment: @DanielDeWet : Calculus tells us that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( 1 + \frac{t^2}{2n}\right)^n = e^{t^2/2}.$ But what about $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1 + \frac{t^2}{2n} + \cdots \right)^n,$ where the dots represent some additional terms after those first two? The question is whether the limit will still be $e^{t^2/2}.$ And that depends on what those additional terms are. It is claimed that if the sum of those additional terms divided by $s^2$ approaches $0$ as $s$ approaches $0,$ then the limit will still be $e^{t^2/2}. \qquad$